# Fluent Nhibernate: fetching collections within collections concurrently

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, task-parallel-library

I needed to eagerly fetch an entity with collections of collections, etc. so that I could process the data concurrently (a Thing entity with many YELLOWEntities that each have many SubYellowEntities). The key code needed was:

```
NHibernateUtil.Initialize(fetchedThings);
```

(See accepted answer below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution (if you can refine this, go ahead and post the revision as the answer):**  Runs in 17 seconds (down from 97) on 8 processors with correct results. Please remember that the vast majority of time was spent in calculations, not in waiting for Nhibernate to return.

```
var fetchedThings = new List<Thing>();
var sessFT = Session.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
Task getThingsTask = new Task(() =>
   {
       fetchedThings = sessFT.CreateQuery(@" from Thing t " +
                             " inner join fetch t.BlueEntity " )
                             .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                             .List<Thing>();
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(fetchedThings);
    });
getThingsTask.Start();

var fetchedYellows = new List<YELLOWEntity>();
var sessFY = Session.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
Task getYellowsTask = new Task(() =>
   {
        fetchedYellows = sessFY.CreateQuery(@" from YELLOWEntity y " +
                             " left join fetch y.SubYellowEntities " + ... )
                             .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
                             .List<YELLOWEntity>();
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(fetchedThings);
    });
getYellowsTask.Start();

getThingsTask.Wait();
getYellowsTask.Wait();

Parallel.ForEach(fetchedThings, thing =>
{
    thing.YELLOWEntities = fetchedYellows.Where(y=>y.Thing.Id == thing.Id).ToList();
    ...
    //...inner foreach() loop through 'YELLOWthings'... doing threadsafe stuff
    ...
});

//dispose the temp sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the current approach. Let me give you a fresh look at the problem.

You are, I understand, looking to retrieve `Things`, which have many-to-one `BlueEntities`, and a collection of `YellowEntities`, which in turn have a collection of `SubYellowEntities`.

Instead of using `join fetch`, transformers and loops, you should look into [batch fetching](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch) of entities and collections.

With a good batch size set for `BlueEntity`, `Thing.YellowEntities` and `YellowEntity.SubYellowEntities`, you should not need TPL stuff at all.

If it turns out you do, you won't be able to return safe-to-use entities, because they have to be associated with a single session to be useful, and sessions are not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for the different perspective. My example is over-simplified. There are several main entities w/ collections, etc to be returned in large sets of data. Overall, Nhibernate was taking about 27 seconds to return. To process the data required another 70 seconds. As it turns out [this here allowed me to get through the parallel processing](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-initialization). On 2 processors, run-time has been halved. I will definitely follow up on your suggestion and warning about sessions.

Comment: `session.Query<Thing>().Where(conditions).ToList()`, and configure batch sizes appropriately to avoid N+1.